# How can I set file permissions from Perl?

Tags: perl

I'm writing a Perl script that generates a Bash script. I'm using `open()` with a mode of `>` to output everything to a new file. Standard stuff:

```
open (FILEOUT, ">", "rename.sh") or die "Can't create rename.sh";
```

The resultant `.sh` file is read only, with an octal value of 444. In perldoc it says I can add a `+` to the `>` (`open (FILEOUT, "+>", "rename.sh")`) to make the newly created file readable and writable, or 666.

Is there a way to make the new file executable (755 or anything else) using `open()`? If not, what's the best way to set file permissions for the new file?

Comment: That's really not what `+>` does.  It has nothing with the file's permissions and instead affects the access mode of the filehandle created by `open`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You will want to [chmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chmod.html) the file like this.

```
chmod 0755, $filename;
#or
chmod 0755, $fh;
```

Alternatively, if you use [sysopen](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysopen.html) and set the [umask](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/umask.html) appropriately, you can do without chmod.

Comment: Excellent. Both options work great. 
I got `sysopen` to work like so: `use Fcntl; sysopen (FILEOUT, "rename.sh", O_RDWR|O_EXCL|O_CREAT, 0755);`

Comment: And don't forget the leading `0`; `chmod 755, $filename` is equivalent to `chmod 01363 $filename`

Comment: @Andrew, That only works if the `umask` is a subset of `022`.

Comment: @Leon Timmermans, Don't need to use `sysopen`. Could just as easily have used `open`.

Comment: @Andrew: The right way would be to use `0777` as the permissions.  Then it's up to the user's umask to choose between `0755` and `0775`.  (or something different, with an unusual umask.)  `open` and `sysopen` have a default mode of `0666`.

Comment: @ikegami: I updated the answer to actually include using the optional permissions arg to `sysopen` (which is the whole point of using it in this case.)  And more importantly, to fix the bad suggestions about using umask instead of leaving it up to the user's umask like `open` does.

Answer (score 2):

Putting `+` infront of `<` or `>` allows you to open the file in both read and write mode.

In you case you can [**chmod**](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chmod.html) the newly created file.